# Linux kernel support for ARP offloading

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to enable DW XGMAC features on Linux. The MAC supports ARP offloading feature, which basically generates ARP reply packets. I can see a function([dwxgmac2_set_arp_offload](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/dwxgmac2_core.c#L1365)) in the XGMAC driver to enable this feature. But I couldn't able to find a way to invoke this function.
ethtool utility is not supporting offloading of ARP. Does the Linux kernel support that, and if so, how can it be enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently accessible from user space.  Some network features may depend on ARP requests being noted.  The [selftest](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/stmmac_selftests.c#n1617) demonstrates how a kernel module (or patch) could be used to implement user space activation.

```
static int stmmac_ioctl(struct net_device *dev, struct ifreq *rq, int cmd)
{
        struct stmmac_priv *priv = netdev_priv (dev);
        int ret = -EOPNOTSUPP;


        switch (cmd) {
        case SIOCGMIIPHY:
        /* ... */
        case SIOARPBYPASS:
          u32 ip = rq->sock_addr...;
          ret = stmmac_set_arp_offload(priv, priv->hw, ip ? true: false, ip);
          break;
```

You need to make the SIOARPBYPASS define and pass an IP address to respond to.  It won't offload if the node responds to multiple addresses, such as IPv6.  It still work for that particular address.